# How to know if files are being successfully compressed?

Tags: node.js, express, compression, gzip

I'm currently using `node.js` with `express` to serve content. However the size of my content was kinda large and I rather gzip the content and have the client unzip and then use the content(specifically javascript) as currently its at `1.4MB` however when gzipped its about `300KB` which is faster to serve over the network especially on mobile. So I started using the [compression](https://github.com/expressjs/compression) library to compress/gzip all files being served over the network. 
I'm wondering to see how I can know if files are being compressed? So far I have the following:

```js
var express = require('express');
var compression = require('compression')
var zlib = require('zlib');

var app = express();
app.use(compression({level: 9}));
```

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

It says that the javascript is still `1.4MB` so I'm not sure if its actually working right now. I'm not sure if theres an indicator because it should be about `300KB`

Comment: The response is not compressed unless you see a header like this in the response headers: `Content-Encoding: gzip`

Comment: Have you found out how you can check if gzip is enabled? I cannot see any Content-Encoding in my response, though I have enabled compression. My response is similar to yours.

Comment: @AntonScotte, similar thing happened to me. I was just adding the compression middleware without using any option due to which my response wasnt being compressed. Once I added filter in it and returned true, it started working and I saw gzip in Content-Encoding of response. 
I am new to this so not sure if this is how we enable compression, but the above workaround worked for me. 
app.use(compression({
        filter: (req, res) => {
          if(req.get('Accept-Encoding').includes('gzip'))
            return true;
          else 
            return false;
        }  }));